# Only delete from memory not from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord array containing a list of shops.

```
shops = Shop.find(:all)
```

I want to delete a record from shops without deleteting it from the database.

`shops.delete(a_shop)` would result in a delete SQL query. I just want the shop to be deleted from the ActiveRecord array but not the database.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Beware** if you are using has_many relationship the answer by JP will not work.

Extending the example:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops
end

city = City.find(:name => "Portland")
```

then

```
city.shops.delete(city.shops[0])
```

**Will** delete from the DB!

Also

```
theshops = city.shops
theshops.delete(ss[0])
```

**Will** delete from the DB

One way to detach from the DB is to use compact or another array function like so:

```
theshops = city.shops.compact
theshops.delete(ss[0])
```

**Will not** delete from the DB

Also, in all cases delete_if **Will not** delete from the db:

```
city.shops.delete_if {|s| s.id == city.shops[0]}
```

Cheers!

Don't forget: If you are in doubt about these sort of things script/console is your friend!

Answer (score 4):

When I did some testing, calling the delete method does not actually delete the element from the database.  Only from the array.

```
shops = Shop.find(:all)
shops.delete(shops[0]) #deletes the first item from the array, not from the DB
```

To delete from the DB:

```
shops = Shop.find(:all)
Shop.delete(shops[0].id)
```

See the distinction?  At least, this how it works on my Rails 2.1 setup.

-JP

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove the item from the array.

However, you should be able to modify your find to return the array without that shop initially. Something like:

```
shops = Shop.find(:all, :conditions => "id NOT #{a_shop.id}")
```

should be along the lines of what you want. That way you never get the shop in the container in the first place, but it doesn't affect the database.

Comment: This will work once, but if more than one shop needs to be removed, you'll have to do something else.

And you can remove items from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest such way to delete AR object in memory.
Add an attribute to the appropriate model that is responsible for marking AR object as deleted (e.g. `deleted` attribute):

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
     attr_accessor :deleted

```
 def deleted
   @deleted || 'no'
 end
```

end

Mark the appropriate object as deleted:

```
o.order_items {|oi| oi.deleted = 'yes' if oi.id == 1029}
```

Filter order_items set only not deleted rows:

```
o.order_items do |oi| 
 unless oi.deleted == 'yes'
 ...
 end
end
```